# WebActivatorEx startup method not running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express, sitemap, iis-10

I have an MVC app that I prefer to test/debug using IIS vs. IIS Express. Until moments ago, all was working fine, yet now suddenly, when I build the project, and use Chrome to navigate to the start page, I get the following error:

> The SiteMapLoader has not been initialized. You must set the
>   SiteMaps.Loader property during Application_Start in Global.asax if
>   the 'MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer' setting is set to
>   'true' in the AppSettings section of web.config.

Yet, if I change the project settings to use IIS Express instead, when I hit F5 my site loads properly, no errors. What could have suddenly changed somewhere for me to get this error now?

In my `Composer` class, that is the default dependency injection composer for the `MvcSiteMapProvider`. It has a `Compose` method that is supposed to run on application startup - `Composer` has the following attribute:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MvcSiteMapProvider.DI.Composer), "Compose")]
```

Yet this `Compose` method is never called when running on IIS. Do I have this attribute on the incorrect class or what? Why shouldn't `Compose` be called after `Application_Start`. If I try explicitly calling `Compose` at the end of `Application_Start`, the app at least starts up, no `SiteMapLoader` error, but it starts up, displays the 'home' page, and as soon as I navigate anywhere, I get an, `There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'.` error.

Answer (score 0):

for this error:

> There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'.

make sure you added below the line in your web.config file:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" optimizeCompilations="false" />
```

or

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
 <!-- In order to provide MVC Intellisense support on Panels during development-->
 <assemblies>
 <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 </assemblies>
```

iis feature static content feature is installed.

[image]

for this error:

> The SiteMapLoader has not been initialized. You must set the SiteMaps.Loader property during Application_Start in Global.asax if the 'MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer' setting is set to 'true' in the AppSettings section of web.config.

you could just add the module and then manually add it to your DI container's configuration by following the steps in the README within the package.

PM> Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC[x].DI.[containerName].Modules

Replace the x with your MVC version and the containerName with the container that you are using.

install the MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.DI.Ninject package

Comment: Thanks, but, as said, I've already narrowed the sitemap error to a `WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod` method not running.

Comment: did you try to set this code `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" optimizeCompilations="false" />
` in web.config file?